# Combining a pointer and an integer in a union

Tags: c, pointers, integer, unions

I have defined a union as follows:

```
union {
  uintptr_t refcount;
  struct slab_header *page;
} u;
```

The `page` pointer is guaranteed to be aligned on a page boundary (most probably 4096), and is never going to be `NULL`. This implies that the lowest possible address is going to be `4096`.

`refcount` will be within `0 .. 4095`.

Upon the creation of the enclosing struct, I can either have `u.refcount = 0` or `u.page = mmap(...)`.

The code around this union is going to be something like that:

```
if (u.refcount < 4096) {
  /* work with refcount, possibly increment it */
} else {
  /* work with page, possibly dereference it */
}
```

Is this always guaranteed to work on a fully POSIX-compliant implementation? Is it ever possible that `uintptr_t` and `struct slab_header *` have different representations, so that, for example, when `u.page == 8192`, `u.refcount < 4096` yields true?

Comment: Assuming that the two usion members _are_ compatible. If refcount will be 0 - 4095, then the page pointer will most certainly be NULL when refcount is 0, because NULL is almost always implemented as either 0 or (void*)0.

Comment: "Is this always guaranteed to work?" - guaranteed by whom? By the standard, no. By any given C implementation's own documentation/ABI, almost certainly yes. Presumably if you're calling `mmap` then a guarantee in Posix would be sufficient, although I'm not claiming there is one.

Comment: @Steve: assuming a fully POSIX-compliant implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that it's "always guaranteed to work", because:

1. `uintptr_t` is optional (7.18.1.4).
2. A `void *` can be converted to `uintptr_t` and back (7.18.1.4). It's not guaranteed that it is the case with `struct slab_header*`. A `void *` has the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type. Pointers to structures needn't have the same representation or alignment (6.2.5 27). Even if this was not the case, nothing guarantees `sizeof(uintptr_t) == sizeof(void *)`, it could obviously be larger and still satisfy the requirement of being convertible to `void *` in the typical case of homogeneous pointers.
3. Finally, even if they have the same size and are convertible, it's possible the representation of the pointer values differs in a strange way from that of unsigned integers. The representation of unsigned integers is relatively constrained (6.2.6.2 1), but no such constraints exist on pointers.

Therefore, I'd conclude the best way would be to have a common initial elements that tells the state.

Comment: 7.18.1.4 says that any valid `void*` value can be converted to `uintptr_t` and back. It doesn't say the reverse, that any valid `uintptr_t` value can be converted to `void*` and back. So indeed `uintptr_t` can be larger than `void*`, and it could also legally be smaller provided that most of the range of the representation of `void*` aren't valid pointers. Not that I've ever seen such strangeness, of course.

Comment: @Steve Thanks, I've fixed the answer accordingly.

Comment: OK, thanks for the precise answer. According to C99, it is not guaranteed because `uintptr_t` need not be of the same size or representation as `void *` or `X *`. To rephrase the question, is there a mainstream POSIX-compliant OS that may have `sizeof(uintptr_t) != sizeof(struct slab_header *)`, running on a mainstream architecture (ARM, x86, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer a different question -- "is this a good idea?"  The more significant worry I see from your code is aliasing issues. I would be unsurprised (in fact, I would mildly *expect* it) if it were possible to write a piece of code that had the effect of

- Write something to `u.refcount`
- Write something to `u.page`
- Read `u.refcount`
- Discover the value you read is the same as what you first wrote

You may scoff, but I've seen this happen -- and if you don't appreciate the danger, it will take a *very* long time to debug.

You may be safe with this particular union; I'll leave it to someone with more experience with this sort of thing (and/or a copy of the C standard handy) to make that judgment. But I want to emphasize that this is something *important* to worry about!!!

There is another cost. Using the union in combination with a "magic" test to discover what is stored in it -- especially one using system-specific facts -- is going to make your code harder to read, debug, and maintain. You can take steps to mitigate that fact, but it will always be an issue.

And, of course, the cost of your code simply not working when someone tries to use it on a weird machine.

The right solution is probably to structure your code in a way so that the only code that cares about the data layout is a couple tiny `inline`d access routines, so that you can easily swap how to store things. Organize your code to use a compile-time flag to choose which one!

Now that I've said all that, the question I really want to ask (and want to get you in the habit of considering): "is it worth it?" You're making sacrifices in your time, code readability, ease of programming, and portability. What are you gaining?

A lot of people forget to ask this question, and they write complex buggy code when simplistic, easy to write and read code is just as good.

If you've discovered this change is going to double the performance of a time-intensive routine, then it's probably worth dealing with this hack. But if you're investigating this simply because it's a clever trick to save 8 bytes, then you should consider it only as an intellectual exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `<stdint.h>` and C99 standard guarantee that `uintptr_t` and `void*` has the same size and can be casted without loss.

Being page aligned for a pointer is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

there should be any problem with that code. But for any case you can have in the init of your program a check:

```
if (sizeof(uintptr_t) != sizeof (struct slab_header*)
{
    print error
}
```

but something seems off (or not clear). you want the "refcount" to be 0 when ever you have a page. and not zero when the page is NULL ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this always guaranteed to work?

No.  You can't read a member of an union different than the last one written.  And optimizers do take that into account, so that isn't a theoretical problem.

> Is it ever possible that uintptr_t and struct slab_header * have different representations,
>   so that, for example, when u.page == 8192, u.refcount < 4096 yields true?

It is also theoretically possible.  I can't think of a current implementation where it occurs.

Comment: That's not true; you can. The standard specifically allows for type punning.

Comment: @Artefacto: that said, C89 only makes very restricted allowance for type punning (unions containing structs with common initial sequences). C99 additionally states that accessing a member of a union type-puns whatever was stored there using another member. In this particular example it's not a legal pun under strict aliasing rules anyway, so although the statement "You can't read a member of an union different than the last one written" is not true in general, it's true of this union as far as the standard is concerned.

Comment: @Steve As for C89, fair enough. But I'm not sure your strict aliasing argument holds. 6.5.7 allows a union type to alias an object. I don't think he wants to use type punning per se (convert an integer to a pointer via the structure and then access the object), so I don't the problem.

Comment: @Artefacto: maybe, but at first glance to me, if he writes a pointer to `u.page` and then reads `u.refcount` as in the code in the question, he's converting a pointer to an integer via the structure, expecting a value >= 4096. It's exactly a type pun, although AFAIK compilers that use strict aliasing for optimization are not in practice strict about this kind of a pun-through-union.

Comment: @Steve Sure, that's a type pun, but what does it have to do with aliasing? He's not accessing any object through a pointer unless he's sure that the union actually contains a pointer, at which point he can use it to access the object. The only problem this would cause would be that actually if a had a function that received a union of this type and this union had the integer, not the pointer, the compiler could not assume the union does not alias a slab_header struct.

Comment: @Artefacto: strict aliasing isn't just about pointers, it's about any access via an lvalue expression. `u.refcount` is an lvalue expression of type `uintptr_t`, but the "effective type" of the object is the type it was written as, `struct slab_header *`. So, by `6.5/7` that object shall *not* have its stored value accessed by the lvalue `u.refcount`. I admit this is all hair-splitting, though, for two reasons: (1) you've already pointed out that the object representations in any case might be incompatible; (2) in practice compilers allow re-interpretation through unions.

Comment: @Artefacto, reference please? I had somewhat the same memory but couldn't find it and as the C99 standard still contains explicit allowance of the X hack -- which would have then been useless -- I though I was misremembering.

Comment: @AProgrammer [C99 + TC1 + TC2 + TC3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Comment: @Artefacto, please chapter and verse. As I said, I searched for it before answering and didn't find any place where it is defined and found mentions which made little sense it is defined.

Comment: @AProgrammer See footnote 82.

Comment: @Artefacto Thanks.  For the record I assume that you are refering to the footnote added in TC3 and referenced 78a in [DR283](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/dr_283.htm).